# How to find out when a user joined Twitter

Tags: twitter, account-management

How can I find out when a user joined Twitter? Is there a way to do this on Twitter, or are there any web services to give me this info?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a good service:

[Howlongontwitter.com](http://howlongontwitter.com/)

Note: [Whendidyoujointwitter.com](http://www.whendidyoujointwitter.com/) currently experiences connection problems and the above one is a working alternative.

Comment: also this one is down

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found [mytweet16.com](http://www.mytweet16.com/) and this service seems to provide this info. For example,

```
FenerbahceHaber joined Twitter on Aug 16th, 2009 (694 days ago).
```

Comment: For some usernames nothing comes up on this one

Comment: Now this website has a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't work anymore. However, I found the site http://www.twitterjoindate.com, which works.

Comment: this does not work now :-/